# Use of \pointssum with selected questions

Tags: exsheets

I would like to select questions by topic, as described in the exsheets manual. However, it seems that the \pointssum command does not respect this, instead adding points of all questions, even those not selected. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\begin{document}
The total number of points is: \pointssum

\SetupExSheets{use-topics={logic}}

\begin{question}[topic=logic]{2}
I want this question.
\end{question}

\begin{question}[topic=algebra]{3}
I don't want this question.
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

In this example, after compiling twice, the \pointssum is equal to 5, not 2. I am using exsheets obtained from TeXLive 2016.

Comment: Please make a bug-report at https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/exsheets

Comment: I've just done that for you: https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/exsheets/issues/36/ Fix and update will follow soon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought it was my fault for doing something wrong, not a bug.